# Error al Imprimir por consola un array Json en php

Tags: php, ajax, json

El problema es el siguiente: Tengo un archivo html con el que, a través de ajax, envío a un archivo php un dato. Éste dato lo recibo en php y al recibirlo codifico un arreglo en json para mostrarlo por consola a través de ajax como respuesta. Todo esto es exitoso siempre y cuando no tenga código html dentro del archivo php en el cual codifico en arreglo, es decir si codifico el arreglo en php para mostrarlo por consola en javascrip (ajax) y tengo código html en el php No Me Funciona y me imprime este error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2, en el codigo javascript marca el error en el JSON.parse(), pero si quito el html del php funciona perfecto. Aqui el codigo AJAX para enviar:

```
       $.ajax({


             url:"prueba.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{"datastring":string},

             success: function(resphtml){

                 var obj = JSON.parse(resphtml);
                 console.log(resphtml);
                 console.log(obj.data1);
             }

         });
```

Este es el php:

```php
 <?php

        if(isset($_REQUEST['datastring'])){


            $dataArray = array('data1' => 10, 'data2' => 'My_nombre', 'data3'=> 10);

            echo json_encode($dataArray);

        }

    ?>
```

Hasta aqui no hay problema, el problema es cuando coloco codigo html en el php

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        if(isset($_REQUEST['datastring'])){


            $dataArray = array('data1' => 10, 'data2' => 'My_nombre', 'data3'=> 10);

            echo json_encode($dataArray);

        }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui ya marca error si imprimo la salida por consola con el error que menciono arriba: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2. Muchas gracias, cualquier aporte estaré atento.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando respondes sin html tu respuesta es un objeto

`echo json_encode($dataArray);`

En cambio, cuando agregas html, se responde de manera diferente ya que se incluyen los tags, lo que impide crear o acceder correctamente al objeto.

Cuando vas a realizar una API o simular algo por el estilo, lo ideal es que sea como lo haces primero, un fichero que solo se encargue de responder en objetos y no con código HTML.

Recuerda que cuando creas respuestas de este tipo en php es importante definir

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Para que la respuesta se considere JSON y no string

Comment: Gracias César, muy útil tus apuntes, voy a colocar la linea que me indicas para ver los resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema surge por el tipo de dato que está recibiendo tu AJAXRequest cuando lo envias a tu archivo php. Con esto quiero decir que, para que este error no te de, debes de tener dos cosas en cuenta:

1) Si lo único que quieres recibir es un JSON, deberías de especificarle a tu función AJAX que eso es lo que debe de esperar. Esos los haces agregando la opción dataType a tu función AJAX. Además de que, si quieres imprimirlo en console, puedes usar la función JSON.stringify(). Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
    $.ajax({
         url:"prueba.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{
            "datastring":string
         },
         dataType:"json",
         success: function(responseJSON){

             var obj = JSON.stringify(responseJSON);
             console.log(obj);
         }

     });
```

2) Recuerda que a tu función AJAX llegará todo lo que esté impreso en tu archivo php, por lo que tener código HTML sería también parte de la respuesta a tu función. Si no es necesario que tengas código HTML, quítalo y verás como hace lo que tiene que hacer y funciona correctamente:

```
<?php

        if(isset($_REQUEST['datastring'])){


            $dataArray = array('data1' => 10, 'data2' => 'My_nombre', 'data3'=> 10);

            echo json_encode($dataArray);

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Gracias Diego, que buen aporte, voy a probar lo que me indicas.